# Regex, capture two groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this two strings:

```
'06BRSU6TX6DfBEIMsD9$Bt',#13,$,$,[#2095, #2333],#2181

.AREA.,'Some, text, here',#609794,310.000000000008,699.999999999997
```

This is my regex `('[^']*'|[^,]+)|([^[\]\,]+)`

The idea is to separate the string by `comma`, but keep "free-texts" with comma.

The first capture group should capture everything between two single quotes.

The second capture group should exclude `[]`.

https://regex101.com/r/jYwK0h/2

The capture groups works if I separate them but not combined.

Comment: Are you after [this](https://regex101.com/r/EJB36Y/1)?

Comment: The [ and ] should not be matched.

Comment: Then use [this `/\[[^\][]*]|('[^']*'|[^,]+)/g` pattern](https://regex101.com/r/EJB36Y/2) and only grab Group 1 values. Are you extracting these values to get an array of them?

Comment: I want an array that should pass an JSON.parse. Henche I want to exclude the [ ] since those values are array.

Comment: Well, do you mean you have arbitrary JSON inside the string? That can have any number of nesting levels? Then you cannot use a regex here.

Comment: The matches later get an ' ' around them. Goal is to be able to run JSON.parse('['06BRSU6TX6DfBEIMsD9$Bt','#13','$','$',['#2095', '#2333'],'#2181']')

Comment: Ah, so it is not parsing out JSON from a larger string, I see. So, you are actually *replacing*. However, see https://jsfiddle.net/L3of1ach/, `JSON.parse("['06BRSU6TX6DfBEIMsD9$Bt','#13','$','$',['#2095', '#2333'],'#2181']")` won't get parsed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156938/discussion-between-per-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Please check my answer, if it works I will add explanations. Else, I will delete.

Comment: I think its to complicated.

Comment: You may think whatever you please, does it solve your problem? If it does, I will explain and you will se how simple it is.

Answer (score 0):

You may match and capture those patterns you need and just match those that you need to discard. In the end, just push the captured values to the resulting array:

```js
var rx = /('[^']*')|\[([^\][]*)]|[^,]+/g;
var strs = ["'06BRSU6TX6DfBEIMsD9\$Bt',#13,$,$,[#2095, #2333],#2181", ".AREA.,'Metallsteg, \\X2\\00F6\\X0\\ppna',#609794,310.000000000008,699.999999999997"];
for (var s of strs) {
   console.log(s.replace(rx, function($0,$1, $2) {
     return $1 ? $1 : $2 ? "[" + $2.replace(/(\s*)([^,]+)/g, "$1'$2'") + "]" : "'" + $0 + "'";
   }));
}
```